# HLS FLAC Audio Stream

Tags: http-live-streaming, flac, amazon-elastic-transcoder, aws-media-convert, aws-elastictranscoder

I have a FLAC audio file (24bit/192Kbps) from which I want to create a HLS packaged adaptive bitrate stream, the highest quality stream being the input format, so FLAC (24bit/192Kbps) and the lower format streams being AAC at different bit rates.

I can do this with AWS MediaConvert or AWS Elastic Transcoder with regard to the AAC outputs but it doesn't support creating the FLAC outputs as far as I can see.

Is there a reason I shouldn't be trying to do this?  Assuming that it is a perfectly valid objective is there another tool/service to do the job or perhaps I need to code something up myself around ffmpeg?

Answer (score 0):

We are currently reviewing FLAC as a roadmap feature and intend to include it in an upcoming MediaConvert release. Please check out the what's new post for released features in MediaConvert.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/media-services/?whats-new-content.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-content.sort-order=desc&awsf.whats-new-products=general-products%23aws-elemental-mediaconvert

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the info.  We are going live with MVP in feb so will have to roll our own solution for now.